# Add sub products programmatically

Tags: product, configurable-product, cart

I'm new to magento and am writing a plugin to allow customisable products be added to cart through an offsite API.

The guts of it are:

1) There is only one product needed in Magento.

2) However each product is unique because it is customized off site. A thumbnail of the customized product is returned for display in cart.

3) Each customized product should appear as a separate item in the cart so the user can differentiate between different customized products

4) All sub-product sales should appear as accumulative for the single product in the backend.

I'm thinking of using Configurable Products and programmatically adding a unique sub-product to add to the cart. Once it's paid for that sub-product can be removed.

Am I on the right track?
Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

found an answer after much searching. Turned out not to be too complicated

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27531980/add-attribute-to-cart-items-in-magento-show-separate-in-cart